# How do I make this python loop increment an int up and down repeating

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, increment

I'm trying to create a fake thermostat that has a set temperature and increments up and down between the minimum and maximum temperatures over time. The minimum is the set temperature - 2 and the max temperature is the set temperature + 1.

Here's the thermostat class:

```
class Thermostat:

    def __init__(self, set_temp = 70, actual_temp = 70):
        self.set_temp = set_temp
        self.actual_temp = actual_temp
        self.max = set_temp + 1
        self.min = set_temp - 2

    def set_the_temp(self, x):
        self.set_temp = x

    def increment_temp(self, x):
        self.actual_temp += x

#create a thermostat
thermostat = Thermostat()
```

Here's what I have for the loop that increments, but I can't figure out the logic for the conditional statements, it always just loops between 70 and 71.

```
def increment_temp():

    last_temp = 69

    def increment(x):
        last_temp = thermostat.actual_temp
        thermostat.increment_temp(x)
        print("set temp: ", thermostat.set_temp)
        print("actual temp: ", thermostat.actual_temp)
        print("last temp:", last_temp)


    while True:
        if thermostat.actual_temp > last_temp:
            if thermostat.actual_temp < thermostat.max:
                increment(1)
            else:
                increment(-1)
        elif thermostat.actual_temp < last_temp:
            if thermostat.actual_temp > thermostat.min:
                increment(-1)
            else:
                increment(1)
        time.sleep(randint(2,10))
```

for the life of me, I can't figure out why actual_temp goes back up to 71 from 70 even when actual_temp is less than set_temp when it's 71.

Answer (score 1):

In here, your last temp you are changing isnt the same as the last temp outside of the function, and that is causing some issues with the code. You can see if you debug that the value of last_temp isn't changing, and is stuck at 69 with your code.

What I would recommend is simply adding an extra parameter to the thermostat, call it last temp, and add the incrementing function as a function of the thermostat itself, something like this:

```
def increment_temp(self, x):
    self.last_temp = self.actual_temp
    self.actual_temp += x
    print("....")
```

It also reduces your code complexity and makes it easier to troubleshoot any further issues.

Answer (score 1):

It's due to the scope of the variable `last_temp`.
You can use the `nonlocal` statement to enable rebinding of a nonlocal.

```
def increment_temp():
    last_temp = 69
    def increment(x):
        nonlocal last_temp
        last_temp = thermostat.actual_temp
```

Answer (score 1):

As the answers have pointed out, the problem was with the scoping of one of your variables. The debugging of this was hard because of the various scopes and conflicting responsibilities within your code.

`increment_temp`, `increment_temp` and `increment` are all method/function names, for example. This makes it hard for the reader to understand which function / class has the responsibility to increment the temperature.

A refactor of this may look something like this:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
import time

@dataclass
class Environment:
    temp: int = 70
        
class Thermostat:
    '''Adjusts temperature to a set point.
    has a max and min temp range around setpoint'''
    def __init__(self, setpoint: int):
        self.setpoint = setpoint
        self.max = setpoint + 1
        self.min = setpoint - 2
        self.rate_of_change = 1

    def connect_to_env(self, env: Environment):
        self.env = env

    def adjust_temp(self, change):
        if self.min < self.env.temp + (self.rate_of_change * change) < self.max:
            self.env.temp += (self.rate_of_change * change)
        else:
            self.rate_of_change *= -1
            self.env.temp += (self.rate_of_change * change)

    def print_reading(self):
        print(f'Setpoint: {self.setpoint}')
        print(f'Environment Temp: {self.env.temp}')
        print(f'Rate of Change: {self.rate_of_change}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thermostat = Thermostat(setpoint=69)
    thermostat.connect_to_env(env=Environment(temp=70))
    while True:
        thermostat.adjust_temp(change=1)
        thermostat.print_reading()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Here the environment holds the data associated with it, the temperature. The thermostat then holds the data relevant to it and the methods which make sense in the context of a thermostat object.

> I can't figure out the logic for the conditional statements, it always just loops between 70 and 71.

Conditional control flow with nested `if` and `elif` statements often indicates that the logic can be simplified. Here there is a `rate_of_change` variable which indicates which way the temperature should be changed.